# Puppeteer: set timeout wait seems to be necessary for Auth0 login

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I am new to puppeteer and seeing some unexpected behavior.  It feels like waitForSelector is not working unless I "sleep" before it.  Code:

```
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();

        await page.goto('page with Auth0 login');

        await page.setViewport({ width: 2180, height: 1085 });

        const signIn = await page.waitForXPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Sign In')]");

        await (signIn as ElementHandle<Element>).click();

        await page.waitForSelector('#username');

        await page.type('#username', 'username');
        await page.type('#password', 'pass');

        await sleep(1000);

        await page.waitForSelector('button[type="submit"]', {
            visible: true,
            timeout: 5000
          });
        await page.click('button[type="submit"]');

        await browser.close();
```

With the (set timeout) "sleep" it works, but without it doesn't click submit but also doesn't fail, strangely.

Does anyone have an idea why?  Other related answers I've found don't mention an issue with waitForSelector needing a sleep before executing.

Comment: Probably because the submit button is there but in a disabled state where it can't be clicked for a moment. You probably want `waitForFunction` to poll on whatever state makes it submittable. Or keep triggering clicks in a loop until one works. Do you have a sample auth0 page I can see?

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to ggorlen for getting me thinking here.  I set out to try his loop suggestion which made me get the ElementHandle return value from my waitForSelector on the submit button.  I didn't easily see any properties I could get from it, though, so I explored available methods just to see how I might differentiate a successful click from a failed one.  Didn't have much luck with properties so I thought I would hover the element and see if I could determine what was happening.  Oddly, hover didn't seem to move my mouse so that I could see what was happening, but somehow it did fix the issue:

```
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto('page with auth0 login');

        await page.setViewport({ width: 2180, height: 1085 });

        const signIn = await page.waitForXPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Sign In')]");

        await (signIn as ElementHandle<Element>).click();

        await page.waitForSelector('#username');

        await page.type('#username', 'username');
        await page.type('#password', 'pass');

        const submitSelector = 'button[type="submit"]';

        const submitElemHandle = await page.waitForSelector(submitSelector, 
          {
            visible: true,
            timeout: 5000
          });

        await submitElemHandle?.hover();

        await page.click(submitSelector);

        await browser.close();
```

No more sleep needed, but maybe ggorlen has an idea why this worked... I definitely don't.